# Fancyhdr does not show page number

Tags: latex

I am struggling with `fancyhdr` package. Specifically, with the following:

```
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{180pt}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{x.png}}
}
```

The header shows up correctly, but the page number is not shown at all, when using `\thispagestyle{mystyle}`. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In none of the standard latex classes is enough room to accommodate an header of `180pt` height without pushing the footer off the page. You can see that the page number is actually printed if you reduce the height of the text area:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{180pt}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-duck}}
}

\usepackage[includeheadfoot,height=15cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{mystyle}

test


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right. Can one set the height of the text area inside `fancypagestyle`, so that it is only active inside that pagestyle?

Comment: This will depend on your documenclass and package. If you use something compatible with the geometry package you can use this package to manually alter the page geometry and after the page switch back to the normal geometry.